# Max double value or NAN as a sentinel value?

Tags: c++, float

I am in need of a sentinel value to use to assign to a double variable initially.
0 or -1 won't work because these values are valid values in my computation and I need a value that will stand out.

Possible choices are:

1. Maximum double value
2. Minimum double value
3. NAN (I would also need a method to check is_nan as well)

How can I accomplish this in the Arduino language?

Comment: AVR GCC doesn't technically support `double` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a matter of personal preference. I like NAN because it is almost
always obvious it cannot be a valid value.

You can test for the value being NAN with
[`isnan()`](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__math.html#ga468be9ed380771eca5a18e812b2470d4).

Comment: Right but do they exist in arduino language? The constant `NAN` and `isnan()` function (in standard c++ it's a std:: library function)

Comment: The link I provided is to the doc of the avr-libc. You can use `NAN` and `isnan()` with no prefix on any AVR-based Arduino. No need to explicitly include `<math.h>`, as the Arduino IDE does that for you (via `<Arduino.h>`). I do not know about the ARM-based Arduinos (e.g., the Due).